# Restoring purchases made with In App Billing

Tags: paid-apps, in-app-purchase

How can I switch the Play Account used for in-app billing?

No matter which account I "activate" in the Market app, all in-app purchases only go through the first account which is contrary to the experience when purchasing normal apps.

When purchasing normal apps, the billed account is the one that was active in the Market app at the time of purchase.

This causes a problem as I am also unable to restore my in-app purchases unless the account that made the purchases is the primary account on the device.

Comment: Can't verify so I'm not adding this as an answer. The account billed will the one that downloaded the app. Purchases can be only restored if they were made with the account that Downloaded the app.

Comment: No that is not true I'm afraid. I tried that before posting the question.

Comment: Strange. My Nexus one (which I originally tested on) displays the incorrect behaviour. Galaxy Nexus responds correctly in the way Richard says above.

Comment: Which one did you use to buy the app/in-app purchase?

Comment: I tried with both phones but only the Galaxy Nexus responded how Google said it should.

Comment: No, I meant which phone you made the in-app purchase with?

Comment: I understood you. I tried with both phones. I did not need to actually make the purchase because the account name is displayed on the final purchase screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked Google. This was their response.

> Thanks for writing in. I understand you would like to know how to
>   choose what account in app purchases are billed to. I apologize for
>   any frustration this has caused. When you go to make an in app
>   purchase the purchase is going to be billed to what ever account was
>   used to download the app the purchase is going through.